# PDF has %C3%A4 in filename, for special character ä - download request gets 404

Tags: pdf, encoding, special-characters, filenames

To simplify my case: I have a PDF named ä.pdf. To offer it for download, I renamed it to %C3%A4.pdf and set the link to href="%C3%A4.pdf". But clicking the link gets a 404 on XAMPP and on the servers of 2 different hosters.

After renaming the PDF to ä.pdf and leaving href on "%C3%A4.pdf", clicking the link gets the PDF.

What a I missing here? I used to think that filenames may never contain special characters - those are always supposed to be encoded to %C3%A4 etc.
And I thought that modern browsers translate %C3%A4 to ä just for visual purposes, for example when showing URLs in the address bar, but actually still go for %C3%A4.

But in my case the browsers read %C3%A4 and actually go for ä - even old and obsolete browsers like IE11 do. IE11 doesn't translate %C3%A4 to ä in the address bar, but still shows a 404 when clicking the link with href="%C3%A4.pdf" and naming the PDF %C3%A4.pdf.
After renaming the PDF to ä.pdf (and leaving href="%C3%A4.pdf") IE11 gets the PDF, which is the same behaviour like all the modern browsers.

Comment: **It's the server not the browser.** _URLs_ cannot contain nonASCII characters, so they are percent-encoded as you did. The browser sends URL including the percent-encoded data to the server, which decodes it to the actual character(s) and depending on your OS and filesystem (which you didn't identify) a filename often _can_ contain them.

Comment: Do no rename the PDF. if you rename it, that is the new name. The `%` escape is a transport thing, so it will converted when doing HTTP requirest. It is not your task to know the HTTP rules and to escape it. (and so also all modern browsers since some years do translation transparently). In your case the %C3 will be encodex with %25C3 (% is %25, so you have a double encoding but single decoding.)

Comment: So reading your comments I understand that the browser asks the server for the file %C3%A4.pdf, the servers translates this request to ä.pdf and looks for a file with exactly that name. So naming the PDF %C3%A4.pdf gets a 404 while ä.pdf gets a 200.
So this is the proper way to do it: encoding the href attribute while leaving the filename unchanged, containing the special character(s).